# Setting background size (of image) for a "scrolling" page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i'm having the trouble that if I have a "long" webpage (where you make your window as big as you can but still need to scroll) the image doesn't "behave" correctly.

I thought that setting the `background-size` property to `cover` would do this but is the image isn't big enough (Which would have to be pretty big) I just get white space once I scroll down the page a little bit. Is there a property that would, say, set the height of the background to 100% then properly scale the image so it has the correct width proportional to the original height?

My solution as of now is having a background color that the image "eases" into, just to make it look smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
 html,body { 
  background: url(yourImg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Or if image isn't big enough, use a background color as well`

```
background: #6DB3F2 url('yourImg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size: 100% 100%;` property.
But that will stretch your image.

If you want to add background to the full webpage then you can add `background-image:('');` property to body.

e.g.

```
body{
  background-image:url('http://backgrounds-free.com/highresolution/l_086.png');
  background-repeat:none;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```